# Date Time Picker Max value validation message not working in windows server 2003

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, validation

I have a windows application and i have a validation to check date time picker control to does not select greater to its maximum value and show a message that "You can't select".

I have validate and showing message in ValueChanged event and its working fine in **windows 7** environment, but when i run this application in **windows server 2003** the date values changes and the message box showing repeatedly for infinite times.

So please suggest any better idea to validate date change to run it in both windows 7 and windows server 2003.

```
My Code

In load event

public void LoadHistoricData()
    {
    // Set its maximum value.

}

private void dtpHInputDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        MessageBox.Show("You can't select greater than maximum date");            
    }

also i have used,

private void dtpHInputDate_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        MessageBox.Show("You can't select greater than maximum date");            
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: show us the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use `jquery` in displaying date calendar.and there you can disable the future dates.so you will not need to add any extra validation for selecting future date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but here i am using windows application so how could i use jquery here???

Comment: You could use jquery in windows application by  including a WebBrowser control in your WinForms or WPF application and use jQuery from within the web browser.  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Comment: Ok i will try, but i want to do this without web browser so if you have any better suggestion then please share...thanks.

Comment: why not setting the MaxDate value to limit users' selection?

Comment: Yes i have set MaxDate value, but i need to show message when user trying to change beyond max date. and message showing repeatedly in Win server 2003.so please suggest.

Comment: really ? but in my test, when you assigned a max date, users can't select a date larger than it, so not need to alert message.